# ¿Cómo hacer que una función se ejecute mientras tengo presionado un botón?

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo un proyecto el cual quiero que al presionar un botón se incremente una o decremente una variable de tipo entero, y se muestre en un Text Edit, ya tengo esa parte pero solo lo hace cuando aprieto el botón, El siguiente paso que quiero implementar es que cuando deje presionado el botón se repita la función de suma o resta cada X tiempo y que cuando suelte el Botón se deje de repetir la función.

Investigue del método `onlongclicklistener` pero solo logro que se ejecute una vez.
Intente usar un `handler` pero  no se como detener el proceso después, y no se si sea la mejor manera de hacerlo.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener,View.OnLongClickListener {

    private String GradosMotor_StringM1 = "179";
    private String GradosMotor_StringM2 = "80";
    private String GradosMotor_StringM3 = "50";
    private String GradosMotor_StringM4 = "0";
    private String GradosMotor_StringM5 = "180";
    private String GradosMotor_StringM6 = "80";

    private int GradosMotor_intM1 = 179;
    private int GradosMotor_intM2 = 80;
    private int GradosMotor_intM3 = 50;
    private int GradosMotor_intM4 = 0;
    private int GradosMotor_intM5 = 180;
    private int GradosMotor_intM6 = 90;


    private EditText editText_M1;
    private EditText editText_M2;
    private EditText editText_M3;
    private EditText editText_M4;
    private EditText editText_M5;
    private EditText editText_M6;

    private Button button_less_M1;
    private Button button_less_M2;
    private Button button_less_M3;
    private Button button_less_M4;
    private Button button_less_M5;
    private Button button_less_M6;

    private Button button_plus_M1;
    private Button button_plus_M2;
    private Button button_plus_M3;
    private Button button_plus_M4;
    private Button button_plus_M5;
    private Button button_plus_M6;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    button_less_M1.setOnTouchListener(this);
    button_less_M2.setOnTouchListener(this);
    button_less_M3.setOnTouchListener(this);
    button_less_M4.setOnTouchListener(this);
    button_less_M5.setOnTouchListener(this);
    button_less_M6.setOnTouchListener(this);

    button_plus_M1.setOnTouchListener(this);
    button_plus_M2.setOnTouchListener(this);
    button_plus_M3.setOnTouchListener(this);
    button_plus_M4.setOnTouchListener(this);
    button_plus_M5.setOnTouchListener(this);
    button_plus_M6.setOnTouchListener(this);



    button_plus_M1.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    button_plus_M2.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    button_plus_M3.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    button_plus_M4.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    button_plus_M5.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    button_plus_M6.setOnLongClickListener(this);

    button_less_M1.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    button_less_M2.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    button_less_M3.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    button_less_M4.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    button_less_M5.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    button_less_M6.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    button_less_M1.setOnLongClickListener(this);


    }//Cierre Funcion onCreate


    //metodos Para sumar o restar grados

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){

            case R.id.button1m:
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "-1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                GradosMotor_intM1=restaGrados(editText_M1,GradosMotor_StringM1,GradosMotor_intM1);
                break;
            case R.id.button2m:
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "-1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                GradosMotor_intM2=restaGrados(editText_M2,GradosMotor_StringM2,GradosMotor_intM2);
                break;
            case R.id.button3m:
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "-1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                GradosMotor_intM3=restaGrados(editText_M3,GradosMotor_StringM3,GradosMotor_intM3);
                break;
            case R.id.button4m:
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "-1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                GradosMotor_intM4=restaGrados(editText_M4,GradosMotor_StringM4,GradosMotor_intM4);
                break;
            case R.id.button5m:
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "-1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                GradosMotor_intM5=restaGrados(editText_M5,GradosMotor_StringM5,GradosMotor_intM5);
                break;
            case R.id.button6m:
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "-1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                GradosMotor_intM6=restaGrados(editText_M6,GradosMotor_StringM6,GradosMotor_intM6);
                break;
            case R.id.button1p:
                // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "+1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                GradosMotor_intM1=sumaGrados(editText_M1,GradosMotor_StringM1,GradosMotor_intM1);
                break;
            case R.id.button2p:
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "+1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                GradosMotor_intM2=sumaGrados(editText_M2,GradosMotor_StringM2,GradosMotor_intM2);
                break;
            case R.id.button3p:
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "+1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                GradosMotor_intM3=sumaGrados(editText_M3,GradosMotor_StringM3,GradosMotor_intM3);
                break;
            case R.id.button4p:
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "+1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                GradosMotor_intM4=sumaGrados(editText_M4,GradosMotor_StringM4,GradosMotor_intM4);
                break;
            case R.id.button5p:
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "+1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                GradosMotor_intM5=sumaGrados(editText_M5,GradosMotor_StringM5,GradosMotor_intM5);
                break;
            case R.id.button6p:
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "+1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                GradosMotor_intM6=sumaGrados(editText_M6,GradosMotor_StringM6,GradosMotor_intM6);
                break;
        }
    }//Cierre Funcion onClick


    public int sumaGrados (EditText editText_M, String GradosMotor_StringM ,int GradosMotor_intM){
        String GradosMotor_String;
        int GradosMotor_int;

        GradosMotor_int = GradosMotor_intM;
        GradosMotor_String = GradosMotor_StringM;

        comprobarTextEdit(editText_M,GradosMotor_StringM ,GradosMotor_intM);

        GradosMotor_String = editText_M.getText().toString();
        GradosMotor_int =Integer.parseInt(GradosMotor_String);
        if(GradosMotor_int > 180){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Ingresa un valor entre 0 - 180",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            GradosMotor_String = String.valueOf(GradosMotor_intM);
            editText_M.setText(GradosMotor_String);

        }else if (GradosMotor_int < 180){
            GradosMotor_int ++;
            GradosMotor_intM =GradosMotor_int;
            GradosMotor_String = String.valueOf(GradosMotor_int);
            editText_M.setText(GradosMotor_String);
        }

        return GradosMotor_intM;
    }


    public int restaGrados (EditText editText_M, String GradosMotor_StringM ,int GradosMotor_intM ){
        String GradosMotor_String;
        int GradosMotor_int;


        GradosMotor_int = GradosMotor_intM;
        GradosMotor_String = GradosMotor_StringM;

        comprobarTextEdit(editText_M,GradosMotor_StringM ,GradosMotor_intM);


        GradosMotor_String = editText_M.getText().toString();
        GradosMotor_int =Integer.parseInt(GradosMotor_String);
        if(GradosMotor_int < 0 || GradosMotor_int > 180){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Ingresa un valor entre 0 - 180",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            GradosMotor_String = String.valueOf(GradosMotor_intM);
            editText_M.setText(GradosMotor_String);
        }else if(GradosMotor_int > 0){
            GradosMotor_int --;
            GradosMotor_intM =GradosMotor_int;
            GradosMotor_String = String.valueOf(GradosMotor_int);
            editText_M.setText(GradosMotor_String);
        }

        return GradosMotor_intM;
    }

    public void comprobarTextEdit(EditText editText_M, String GradosMotor_StringM , int GradosMotor_intM){
        String GradosMotor_String;
        if(editText_M.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
            if(GradosMotor_intM == Integer.parseInt(GradosMotor_StringM)) {
                editText_M.setText(GradosMotor_StringM);
            }else{
                GradosMotor_String = String.valueOf(GradosMotor_intM);
                editText_M.setText(GradosMotor_String);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {

            case R.id.button1m:
                restaGradosRepetible();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void restaGradosRepetible() {
        final Handler handler= new Handler();

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                GradosMotor_intM1 = restaGrados(editText_M1, GradosMotor_StringM1, GradosMotor_intM1);//llamamos nuestro metodo
                handler.postDelayed(this,500);//se ejecutara cada 10 segundos
            }
        },2000);//empezara a ejecutarse después de 5 milisegundos
    }

}//Cierre Main Activity
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

te recomendaría leer este post en ingles 
[Link donde lo explican en ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938516/continuously-increase-integer-value-as-the-button-is-pressed)

Igual te lo traduciré la respuesta de la persona en ingles

Crea un handler en tu activity o fragment

```
private Handler repeatUpdateHandler = new Handler();
```

Crea dos variables para saber que estado es usando incrementar o reducir la cantidad

```
private boolean mAutoIncrement = false; //Incrementar
private boolean mAutoDecrement = false; //Reducir
```

Crea un entero para determinar el numero que cambiara

```
public int mValue;
```

Crea una clase en tu activity donde correra la logica de incrementar o reducir

```
class RptUpdater implements Runnable {
   public void run() {
       if( mAutoIncrement ){
           increment();
           repeatUpdateHandler.postDelayed( new RptUpdater(), REP_DELAY );
       } else if( mAutoDecrement ){
           decrement();
           repeatUpdateHandler.postDelayed( new RptUpdater(), REP_DELAY );
       }
   }
}
```

Crea la función onLongPressListener para tu boton de aumentar (Crea una igual para el de boton de reducir)

```
mBTIncrement.setOnLongClickListener( 
        new View.OnLongClickListener(){
            public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
                mAutoIncrement = true;
                repeatUpdateHandler.post( new RptUpdater() );
                return false;
            }
        }
);   

mBTIncrement.setOnTouchListener( new View.OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if( (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) 
                && mAutoIncrement ){
            mAutoIncrement = false;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Por ultimo crea tus funciones para aumentar y reducir

```
//para reducir
public void decrement(){
   mValue--;
   _value.setText( ""+mValue );
}
//para Aumentar
public void Aumentar(){
   mValue++;
   _value.setText( ""+mValue );
}
```

Comment: ¿Tendría que crear una Clase RptUpdater  para cada par de botones que quiera usar? ya que al parecer no le puedo pasar argumentos a mi función de suma y resta. Mis funciones ocupan argumentos que leen de un texedit

Comment: Hola, no usas el mismo por eso la clase RptUpdater tiene un if si vas a incrementar o reducir :D

Comment: Hola, si te sirvio la respuedta ponla como correcta :D

Comment: No me deja puntuar, parece que necesito una puntuación mayor a 15 para que se vea reflejado.

Comment: No hay ptoblema, pero ya pusiste como problena resuelto :D

Answer (score 0):

Funciono el método de CarlosGub. Mi resultado quedo de la siguiente manera

Use dos boolean y un Handler llamado handlerRepetir

```
private boolean AutoIncrement_boolean = false; //Incrementar
private boolean AutoDecrement_boolean = false; //Reducir

private Handler handlerRepetir= new Handler();
```

Esta fue mi clase usando implements Runnable

```
    class handlerRepetir_class implements Runnable{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(AutoIncrement_boolean){
            sumaGrados(GradosMotor_intM1,editText_M1);
            handlerRepetir.postDelayed(this,100);//se ejecutara cada x mili segundos
        }else if (AutoDecrement_boolean){
            restaGrados(GradosMotor_intM1,editText_M1);
            handlerRepetir.postDelayed(this,100);//se ejecutara cada x mili segundos
        }
    }
}
```

La función onLongClick y el metodo onTouch funcionaron bien pero funcionan para un solo par de botones, uno para sumar y otro para restar.

Mi duda es que si puedo crear una función o clase con un Runnable que acepte parámetros ya que con mi código actual tendría que crear una nueva clase para cada par de botones.

Comment: Por el momento lo que se me ha ocurrido es agregar mas private boolean AutoIncrement_boolean2 = false; etc y comprobar a través de sentencias if que boolean es verdadero

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias formas de lograr esto, pero una muy simple sería publicar un `Runnable` en un `Handler` con un cierto retraso. De esta forma la acción se realizara una y otra vez hasta que botón deje de estar presionado. En su forma más básica, se verá algo de esta forma:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    private Handler mHandler;

    @Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch(event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            if (mHandler != null) return true;
            mHandler = new Handler();
            mHandler.postDelayed(mAction, 500);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            if (mHandler == null) return true;
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mAction);
            mHandler = null;
            break;
        }
        return false;
    }

    Runnable mAction = new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            System.out.println("Performing action...");
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 500);
        }
    };

});
```

La idea es bastante simple: publicar un `Runnable` que contenga la acción repetida en un `Handler` cuando se produce la acción táctil `ACTION_DOWN`. Después de eso, no vuelva a publicar el `Runnable` hasta que haya pasado la acción táctil `ACTION_UP`. El `Runnable` seguirá publicándose en el `Handler` (mientras que la acción táctil `ACTION_DOWN` todavía está ocurriendo), hasta que se elimine con la acción de retoque, que es lo que permite el aspecto repetido.

Dependiendo del comportamiento real del botón y de tu clic, sobre lo que estas buscando, es posible que desees realizar la publicación inicial sin demora.